# taking numbers and calculation

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

a program that takes alot of number from the user and when q is entered, it calvulates the sum max min and average.

```
n = input("Please enter a number:")
count = 0
min = 0
max = 0
sum= 0

while n !="q" and n !="Q" and n !="Quit":
    n = input("Please enter another number:")
    n1 = float(n)
    sum += n1
    count = count +1
```

Comment: `n !="q" and "Q" and "Quit"` must be `n !="q" and n != "Q" and n !="Quit"`, or, better, `n not in ("Q","q","Quit")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are 3 issues here:

1. You need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.
2. `while n !="q" and "Q" and "Quit":` will not work because its not comparing `n` to each of `"q"`, `"Q"` and `"Quit"`. It should be `while n !="q" and n != "Q" and n != "Quit":`
3. It won't work if there is a single number. Better put your `n = input("Please enter another number:")` at the end of the while instead of first line.

Try this:

```
n = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
count = 0
min = None
max = 0
sum= 0

while n !="q" and n!="Q" and n!="Quit":
    n1 = float(n)

    if min is None:
        min = n1
    elif n1 < min:
        min = n1

    if n1 > max:
        max = n1

    sum += n1
    count = count +1
    n = raw_input("Please enter another number:")

print("Total:", sum)
print("Count:", count)
print("Min:", min)
print("Max:", max)
print("Average:", sum/count)
```

Comment: n = input("Please enter a number:")
    count = 0 
    min = 0
    max = 0
    sum= 0

    while n !="q" and n !="Q" and n !="Quit":
     n1 = float(n)
     sum += n1
     count = count +1
     n = input("Please enter another number:")
    print (count)
    print(sum)                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     so i did this but i still want to get the minvalue and maxvalue and the total. how can i do that?

Comment: but why is it  if min is None?  can it be something else?

Comment: We need to initialize `min` with something. If we keep it `min=0` then if the number provided is negative, the condition will fail. A better way can be to initialize min with -Infinity something like `min=-float('inf')` and then we can get rid of the `if min is None` check.

Comment: alright i got that. but i have another question. can i put the if min is None and elif n<min into one line? or like in a different if elif or if else or if elif else statemtents?

Comment: If you club it in with other if-elif-else block, then may be if does not get executed every time in the loop which means the min calculation might not be correct at the end of loop. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What I want to do is to have another code that runs the same and does the same thing but the other one has a different format

Comment: Without knowing how different the other code piece is to this one, its difficult to say but its better to not club it with another if-else block.

Comment: at the beginning, can i put min = 0 instead of min = None ?

Comment: If the numbers provided by user will all be positive, yes you can.

Comment: one last question i hope so, can i use if elif elif instead of if elif if ?

Comment: If you use if elif elif and if the user provides a single number and then provides `q` to quit, the while loop is executed only once. `min` would be set correctly but  the statement for `max` won't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in Python functions for this:

```
nums = []

n = input("Please enter a number (or q to quit):")
while n not in {"Q","q","Quit"}:
    nums.append(int(n))
    n = input("Please enter a number (or q to quit):")

print("Count: {}, Max: {}, Min: {}, Sum: {}, Average: {}".format(len(nums),max(nums),min(nums),sum(nums),sum(nums)/len(nums)))
```

Comment: shouldnt there be any equations for the max and min and total within the code?

Comment: No, basically what I am doing is storing all of the integers inside a list.  Then I use the Python functions to pull out relevant data, like the max value, or the min value, etc.  Python has lot's of very powerful built in functions.